# What caching headers prevent browsers from requesting last modified dates from the server?

Tags: apache, optimization, caching, http-headers

Since I version all my css/js/images, they never "change". *It might go from sprite.4.png to sprite.5.png, but sprite.4.png will never change.*

Anyway, it seems pointless for the browsers to be checking for modified versions and receiving 304 responses, so what do I need to put in .htaccess to prevent these last modified look ups?

Right now I have,

```
<ifmodule mod_expires.c>
  <filesmatch "\.(jpg|gif|png|css|js|swf)$">
   ExpiresActive On
   ExpiresDefault "access plus 10 years"
   </filesmatch>
</ifmodule>
```

but I still see the 304's in the browsers. What else do I need? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also add:

```
Cache-Control: public
```

to the headers. That will allow clients and proxies to cache the output

In .htaccess:

```
   <filesmatch "\.(jpg|gif|png|css|js|swf)$">
       Header set Cache-Control "max-age=1000000000, public"
   </filesmatch>
```

Comment: @Philippe, it worked! You also gave me some new keywords to search google for and read more about, and I found this: http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/apache-speed-last-modified.html along with some other great tips. Thanks!